# Altium adding custom component to PCB

Tags: altium

I have designed a custom library component in altium. I have done both the schematics and the footprint. Made sure that the PIN designators are matches in the schematic and footprint. Assigned that footprint to the schematic. Now when I try to import the changes to the PCB all components are added except this one. I have taken some screenshots of the component. If you need some more information, do let me know..

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Our buddy, Asmyldof, from the EESE has a dedicated chat room for Altium related questions. [Try asking here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54101/altium-support-room). Going into his chat room is like waking up a tired god that's been sleeping for a thousand years.

Comment: Did you "Update all schematics" with this particular component. ?

Comment: Hi @MITURAJ, I have this component only in one place and yes updated it.. Trying to update again and again :(

Comment: Have you actually imported the Footprint into the Schematic component as a linked item? If all your pins are named correctly it should find the links if the footprint was linked to the schematic symbol. Most common reason for it not to is that you forgot to do that. And @KingDuken made me laugh. Edit: Saw your picture of the footprint model... Thinking while brushing my teeth.

Comment: Hi @Asmyldof, Yes, I did, I have posted the screenshot of that as well. I am you altium chat room, can we please talk there? I can send you information quick there..

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.. Asmyldof pointed to it.. Altium did not like the "Space" in the component name. Removed the space, replaced with "dash", removed the footpring from the schematic, added the footpring back, removed the component from schematic, added back and Altium happily added it to the PCB.. :)

Comment: Good catch.....